# Apache Ignite : Out of memory in data region [name=Default_Region, initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=68.0 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false]

Tags: bigdata, ignite, in-memory-database, in-memory

We got Out of memory in data region in our Apache Ignite production environment, and Ignite process got killed.
We have configured off heap memory of 68 GB. And no eviction policies are enabled as we don't want to loose any data from Ignite. Also we didn't enable persistence as we want to store whole data in Ignite only.

```
class org.apache.ignite.internal.mem.IgniteOutOfMemoryException: Out of memory in data region [name=Default_Region, initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=68.0 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false] Try the following:
  ^-- Increase maximum off-heap memory size (DataRegionConfiguration.maxSize)
  ^-- Enable Ignite persistence (DataRegionConfiguration.persistenceEnabled)
  ^-- Enable eviction or expiration policies
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.pagemem.impl.PageMemoryNoStoreImpl.allocatePage(PageMemoryNoStoreImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.freelist.AbstractFreeList.allocateDataPage(AbstractFreeList.java:463)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.freelist.AbstractFreeList.insertDataRow(AbstractFreeList.java:501)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.RowStore.addRow(RowStore.java:97)
```

The cause of this error is occupying entire data-region (68 GB)? If yes can we handle this from stopping Ignite service?

Answer (score 5):

I think the error is exactly as described and the three solutions are all valid.

1. Give Ignite more memory
2. Define an eviction policy, so records are removed and you don't run out of memory
3. Use Ignite persistence, which stores any data that won't fit in memory on disk

If you can't allocate more memory and want to keep everything in Ignite, it looks like option 3.

> Also we didn't enable persistence as we want to store whole data in Ignite only.

To be clear: Ignite has two kinds of persistence. Third-party persistence, where Ignite saves a copy of its data to a legacy database. And [native persistence](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/persistence/native-persistence), which Ignite manages itself. The suggestion above is mostly about the latter

Comment: Yes, Ignite's native persistence good enough. Any way we wold like fit our data in memory only for better throughput. So, is there feasibility to check data region availability before loading cache to Ignite. So that we can restrict data load activity to Ignite. Because we can be safe from getting out of memory exception and mainly saved from Ignite being down.

Comment: Monitor memory usage and scale your cluster out before there is no more space left in RAM: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/monitoring-metrics/metrics#monitoring-amount-of-data